# How do I get my player to collide with the platform then go back to the ground after jumping off

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to pygame and need to understand how to collide with the platform. So far I am able to jump onto the platform but when I walk off my character moves off screen. As well as this when I jump under the platform my character gets stuck in it and doesn't come back down.

```
class User:
    def __init__ (self,x,y,width,height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel_x = 8
        self.vel_y = 8
        self.gravity = 1
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.jumping = False
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 11, 29, 52)
        self.visible = True
        self.standingstill = True
        self.health = 250
        self.number_left = 0
```

Here is the main part of my player class

```
if player.hitbox[1] < platform_img.hitbox[1] + platform_img.hitbox[3] and player.hitbox[1] + player.hitbox[3] > platform_img.hitbox[1]:
    if player.hitbox[0] + player.hitbox[2] > platform_img.hitbox[0] and player.hitbox[0] < platform_img.hitbox[0] + platform_img.hitbox[2]:
        player.collision()
```

Here is what I'm using for the collision detection but I'm aware there is a built in collision technique. If this is easier could you please show how it would work with my code and where I would implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Please show all the code so I can give a better answer, what does `player.collision()` do? (I don't have enough rep to just comment)